# Wrapping an opengl object into a c++ class with copying

Tags: c++, opengl, copy-constructor

How is this usually done?

For example you might have a texture class. This would of course hold the GLuint id, and maybe other fields such as width and height. When the object needs to be copied for whatever reason, a user-defined copy constructor is needed.

Now, in the case of an opengl texture, it is possible to copy it to another texture object. But what about shader programs, or FBOs? These can't be copied so easily. How do people usually go about doing this? Should they be reference counted? Should copying be disabled on all objects? Should copying be disabled on all objects that can't be copied?

What is the best way to go about this? Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something like a texture there may actually be a point to copying it, but for a shader object much less so (in my experience). Even for objects where copying makes sense, you don't want to do it very often so you want to make it very explicit.

Either you use your wrapper class by-value (so it is something like a handle to your OpenGL entity) and it uses reference counting internally, or you consider your wrapper class instance to own the OpenGL entity and you use reference counting on your wrapper class itself (using std::shared_ptr for example).

In the latter case you could implement a copy-constructor only on those entities for which it makes sense. However, in order to avoid unintentional use I normally resort to a private constructor and a public static factory function on the entity that returns a new instance as a smart pointer, so it is not mistakenly used by-value. In that case it also makes more sense to have an explicit "Copy/Clone" member function (easier to use and it allows for polymorphism).

In the former case the copy-constructor only increments the reference count, so you will need to add some explicit member for copying where appropriate anyway.

I usually go with the latter option by the way... I'm used to passing resource-intensive objects around by smart pointers and I don't see much point in reimplementing their functionality in custom handles.

Comment: Thanks. Would you also implement a move constructor?

Comment: If you use the handle-approach it might be useful (saves you a reference decrement/increment). If you use smart pointers: at least std::shared_ptr already implements one for you. If you always use your class instances via smart pointers there's no point in it having its own move constructor.

Comment: I also use this sort of approach.  See https://github.com/jherico/gl/blob/master/GlBuffers.h where I've created a class to wrap vertex / index buffers.  The basic gl::VertexBuffer holds the OpenGL handle, but applications which wish to use a buffer would declare gl::VertexBufferPtr, which is a typedef for std::shared_ptr<gl::VertexBuffer>.  This means I can pass the objects around as much as I like and not worry about losing the pointer or getting superfluous copies of the data.